# Get all rows even if not existe - SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables :

### T1:(sales per store)

```
`Store  Sales  DateT
A01    100    01-01-22
B01    200    01-01-22
C01    300    01-01-22`
```

### T2 :(store)

```
`CodeStore  Name
A01        Name1
B01        Name2
C01        Name3
D01        Name4`
```

I want to get all rows of both tables, even if there is no sales in a store.
For ex : in table T1, there's no sales for the store D01 in this date (01-01-22) : but i want to get this record.

### expected result :

```
`Store  Sales
A01    100
B01    200
C01    300
D01    `
```

I'v tried this code, but the store D01 doesn't appear :

```
`SELECT CodeStore, sum(Sales)
FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON CodeStore = Store
where DateT = '01-01-22'
group by CodeStore`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What results are you getting from your current query?

Comment: I'm getting all the recodrs expect the store D01

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the two tables in your query so that all records from T2 will be included. Also, the `DateT` filter should be in the join criteria (in the ON clause) now since it filters `T1`.

```sql
SELECT CodeStore, sum(Sales)
FROM T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 ON CodeStore = Store AND DateT = '01-01-22'
group by CodeStore
```

Using a left join (`LEFT OUTER JOIN`) ensures that even if there isn't a matching row in the joined table (`T1`), all the rows from the table in the select (`T2`) will be included in the result.

Comment: You also need to move the WHERE on DateT to the ON clause

Comment: Thank you for your Help. It works when i moved Date in the on clause

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept it as answer so it's easy to find as an answer:)